# How do I make theses values next to each other with commas in between theme

Tags: python, format

I want these format theses to be 1girl, belt, etc.. what can I do to achieve this?

1girl
belt
breasts
gloves
long_hair
long_sleeves
medium_breasts
military
solo
uniform
white_gloves

[Here's what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phY42.png)
I want them side by side with commas

I don't know what to do to get what I want. It's probably something either really simple or hard

Comment: Can you post the code you got so far and maybe explain what you want to happen a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these, depending on what you need:

```
newstr = ', '.join(str.split(' ')) ## if you want the separator to be an empty space
print(newstr)
```

or

```
import re
newstr = ', '.join(re.split('\s|_', str)) ## if you want the separator to be an empty space or _
print(newstr)
```

're' is a module made to work with regex (regular expression)